# How do I save where I was even if I have escaped the program in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been recently trying to make a program that it is saved even if you quit the program
The code

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def disabled():
    button["state"] = "disabled"
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me",  command=disabled) # when you click the command will disable it
button["state"] = "normal" # first
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want from the button to be disabled even if I have escaped

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) then post back with a specific question. BTW, what's with the blank lines?

Comment: Write to a file and then read from the file.

Comment: do  you mean read it as you read from text file ```.read()```

Comment: There is no built-in facility that will do what you want. You have to do it yourself. Write a function that collects the state of all the controls you want to save and write it out to a file using `.write`. Then write another function that reads that file (yes,  use `.read`) and sets the state of the controls accordingly. Then decide where your program should call those functions.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel the blank lines is for me when to separate different parts of the code